Is it possible for a quaternion to represent a rotation pass 180 degree?
I am wondering if quaternions can be used to represent a rotation that is beyond 180 but below 360 degrees?
I am asking this in the context of Unreal Engine's FQuat library where my combined quaternion has a rotation greater than 180 degrees, and it will flip the direction of the resulting quaternion.
Is this unique to Unreal Engine? Or is there something more to quaternions, that I am not aware of?
Any guidance is appreciated, Thanks!
For example, if I combined two 95 degree clockwise quaternions, I expect a 190 degree clockwise quaternion. But in Unreal Engine, it would give a 80 degree counter clockwise quaternion.

Quaternion can represent all possible orientation. If you are talking about rotation as "rotation velocity" than NO.

Yes, as long as you don't try to keep the sign of the scalar part positive. E.g., here is MATLAB code that forms a quaternion q with a 95 degree rotation. Then multiply by itself to get a quaternion p with a 190 degree rotation. Note that the scalar part of p is negative (scalar is first in MATLAB). Then extract the angles of these two quaternions with the atan2d() function to show that you can recover the angle greater than 180:
The code:
angle = 95 % degrees
q = quaternion(cosd(angle/2),sind(angle/2),0,0) % form quaternion with 95 degree rotation
p = q * q % form quaternion with 190 degree rotation 
[a,b,c,d] = q.parts; % extract quaternion parts ...
qd = [a,b,c,d]; % ... and form as double vector
[a,b,c,d] = p.parts; % extract quaternion parts ...
pd = [a,b,c,d]; % ... and form as double vector
atan2d(norm(qd(2:4)),qd(1))*2 % extract angle of q
atan2d(norm(pd(2:4)),pd(1))*2 % extract angle of p

The result of running the code:
angle =
    95
q = 
  quaternion
     0.67559 + 0.73728i +       0j +       0k
p = 
  quaternion
    -0.087156 +  0.99619i +        0j +        0k
ans =
    95
ans =
   190

I am unfamiliar with Unreal Engine and how it deals with quaternions, so can't advise you on that. But it sounds like maybe something in the way the quaternions are formed, or maybe something in the background angle calculations, is forcing the scalar part to be positive by flipping all of the signs?
This can actually be a potential problem with attitude control systems that try to move from one attitude to a nearby attitude. If you are not careful with the signs, the control system can inadvertently be sent the "long" way around instead of the short way. To prevent this, one would intentionally check the scalar sign first and adjust the calculations to force the short way is taken.

Hello, Thank you for the response!! It was indeed like you said, Unreal's quaternion library changes the scalar part to be positive and flip the axis to get smallest rotation geo disc to ensure the rotation doesn't flip direction between tick. I was able to get the quaternion in the "right direction" by calling FQuat::SlerpFullPath.

Quaternion can represent all possible orientations in 3d. If you are talking about rotation as "rotation velocity", in other words describing rotational motion than NO.
There is no "clockwise quaternion". Both quaternions, any and same with negated signs describe same rotation.
for example both define same rotation
0.67559 + 0.73728i +       0j +       0k
-0.67559 + -0.73728i +       0j +       0k

If you want that rotation axis (imaginary part) was pointed to certain direction, than you can choose corresponding sign for it (just multiply by -1).
Please  describe problem you want to solve.

Thank you for the response!
It looks like Unreal's Quat library forces the scalar part to be positive and invert ijk to enforce smallest rotation arc, I was able to get around it by calling it FQuat::SlerpFullPath()!
